# QueryString with MVC 5 AttributeRouting in Web API 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, query-string

I have the following code

```
[HttpGet] 
[Route("publish/{id}")] 
public IHttpActionResult B(string id, string publishid=null) { ... }
```

So as far as I understood,

```
~/..../publish/1?publishid=12
~/..../publish?id=1&publishid=12
```

Should work and bind both parameters but it won't work on the second case.
In the first case, publishid will not be bound.

So I do not understand why this is not working. Any idea why it is in this way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The second case will not work because `id` is a required variable in the route template `publish/{id}`. In Web API first route template matching happens and then the action selection process.

other cases:

1. `publish/1` - will not work as action `B` is saying that publishid is required. To prevent this you can change the signature of action to be something like `B(string id, string publishid=null)` and only `id` is bound
2. `publish/1?publishid=10` - works as expected where both are bound.

Comment: Thanks, I actually I am doing "string publishid=null" I just forgot to put it in my question. I edited the code in the question.

Comment: How about ~/..../publish?id=1&publishid=2 I think that is also valid but still is not working for me. it will give me 404 Not Found !

Comment: Actually by `second case` i meant this scenario...This will not work because `id` is a required variable in the route template `publish/{id}`. In Web API first route template matching happens and then the action selection process...