# The route template cannot start with a '/' or > '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, routeattribute

I am getting the an exception with the following route attribute:

```
[Route("{id}?action=decline")]
```

**Exception:**

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Web.Http.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: The route template cannot start with a '/' or
>   '~' character and it cannot contain a '?' character.

Why is this not allowed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this isn't allowed, because a query string is not part of a URI-Path. (See [RFC3986 Section 3.3 Path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) , it doesn't include the query part)
But I have no hard fact to prove that :/.
Perhaps these links help you:

[Routing based on query string parameter name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12619587/routing-based-on-query-string-parameter-name)
[QueryString with MVC 5 AttributeRouting in Web API 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20834018/querystring-with-mvc-5-attributerouting-in-web-api-2)
[Attribute Routing in ASP.NET Web API 2](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Answer (score 3):

you can do this and you'll have access to both `id` and `action`:

```
[Route("{id}")]

public IHttpActionResult YourMethod([FromUri] string action)
```